# Pygame simple score system

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a simple score system for my pygame. but it's pausing the game. I know it's because of time.sleep but I don't how to sort it out.

The score system is to +100 every 5 seconds while start is true, code:

```
while start == True:
   time.sleep(5)
   score = score + 100
```

Full code with indentation: http://pastebin.com/QLd3YTdJ 
code at line : 156-158

Thank you

Comment: `x == True` is never what you want. just do `while start:`

Comment: You might be interested in [pygame.time](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you dont want the `while True: score += 100` loop to block your entire program?

You should solve it by moving the score adding to a seperate function
and use the intervalfunction of APScheduler http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/intervalschedule.html

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Schedule job_function to be called every 5 seconds
@sched.interval_schedule(seconds=5)
def incr_score():
    score += 100
```

This will result in APScheduler creating a thread for you running the function every 5 seconds.

you might need to do some changes to the function to make it work but it should get you started at least :).

Comment: that looks like the ideal solution to use but I'm getting this error     import Scheduler
ImportError: No module named Scheduler, any idea ?

Comment: You have to install it, ie. `pip install apscheduler`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `sleep`, which stalls the game until time has elapsed, you want to count up an internal timer with the number of seconds which have passed. When you hit 5 seconds, increment the score and then reset the timer.

Something like this:

```
scoreIncrementTimer = 0
lastFrameTicks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
while start == True:
    thisFrameTicks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    ticksSinceLastFrame = thisFrameTicks - lastFrameTicks
    lastFrameTicks = thisFrameTicks

    scoreIncrementTimer = scoreIncrementTimer + ticksSinceLastFrame
    if scoreIncrementTimer > 5000:
        score = score + 100
        scoreIncrementTimer = 0
```

This could easily be improved (what if your frame rate is so low there's more than 5 seconds between frames?) but is the general idea. This is commonly called a "delta time" game timer implementation.